# 2013 Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

SharePoint Stack Exchange's [second moderator election](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Robert Lindgren] [image: PirateEric] [image: Benny Skogberg]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5686761648816128/0).

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations to all 3 of you.

Welcome aboard :-)

Comment: Thank you, Anders. It takes a while to get used to the powers. Previous vote to close, just closes a question. Gotta be careful... :)

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations to our new moderators, hope you guys will continue the good work in keeping the site active and providing solutions for our issues :)

Comment: Thanks Karthik. Expect nothing but the best :)

Answer (score 2):

They need to have a thumbs-up 'like' button in this forum :-)

Congratulations to the new appointees..

Comment: LOL! But this isn't [insert any community having likes]. But on these rare occations, I agree. Like!

Answer (score 1):

Awesome, highly inspired by the clean results.. truly deserved :)

Answer (score 1):

Had I enough rep to vote I would have voted for you guys, congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

Congrats to newly elected Moderators.

Thanks for taking out your personal time to do moderation of this site and provide online assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Well done all.  Good luck in the new roles.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats to all three of u. I got in touch with Robert and Eric regularly with the work they were doing here.

I wish great luck for all of you for the new role.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats to all of you, enjoy the great days!

Answer (score 1):

Congrats to all of you...and you guys really awesome.